# Background-color have a strange behavior

Tags: html, asp.net, css, vb.net

I have a table :

```
<table id="TableCorpsDetails" runat="server" cellpadding="20" bgcolor="<%=BgColor%>" border ="1" align="center" width="50%">
```

And in my vb code, I bind a blue color (from which a sql request):

```
BgColor = myDS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Couleur").ToString
```

And when I execute that code the color of the background is Green and I don't know why...
I didn't have this behavior before I add the `runat="server"` property.
I fixed this problem by removing the `BgColor` parameter and working only with vb code :

```
TableCorpsDetails.Style.Add("Background-color", .Item("Couleur").ToString)
```

But why the `runat="server"` impact the `background-color` ?

Comment: Usually you use runat="server" when you want to use the (table) on the server side code.

Comment: Yes I know. I needed for further processing and when I add this property my Background-color changed wihout particular reason.